# How to become a great cybersecurity professional?

Tags: professional-education

I am scheduled to graduate college with a BS in cybersecurity in October. However, whenever I look up different cybersecurity topics and such I find that there are many many topics that I have no exposure to. I understand that there is a lot to cybersecurity and I am trying to be the best of the best. So my question is, what can I do further enhance myself and become a great cybersecurity professional?

Comment: Information security is a very broad field. Only you can decide what you are interested in. What is your background (not really sure what a "cyber security" degree covers)? Do you want to do offensive or defensive work? Policy, secure software development, web applications, embedded devices, IoT, mobile, forensics, crypto, etc. It is not uncommon to be interested/well versed across multiple disciplines as well.

Comment: Welcome to the InfoSec SE! As a practicing infosec professional I will answer in a bit. I encourage you to join in the InfoSec chat room, The DMZ, to interact with fellow professionals

Comment: Your question is undefined. What makes you a "great cybersecurity professional"? Does one need to be exposed to all possible topics in order to be great? There are 52 job domains in cybersecurity. No one is expert in all topics in all job domains. Even if your question was refined and forced to "how do I become a great SOC analyst?" it would help, but it would still be highly subjective. What's your goal?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking up *entry-level* or actually *intermediate* infosec certifications, as you do already have a degree in Cyber Security hence intermediate would seem like a good fit.

> I find that there are many many topics that I have no exposure to

As I can tell from your post that you are seeking **more on knowledge** than the prestige that the certifications might bring.

- CompTIA Security+
- Certified Ethical Hacker (CEH)
- GIAC Security Essentials (GSEC)

These certifications might give you the initial foothold & exposure you need.

> I am not quite sure which one I should go for as so many jobs list so many different certs as qualifications

Do not take up certs for the purpose of getting specific jobs that lists them as requirements. The certifications I mentioned above are general-purpose certs that cover a wide range of topics and it is should not be taken as a specialization of a certain skill/topic in this field.

**Gain interest** in the certs you want to pursue, **obtain them**, then **start looking** for jobs that list them as prerequisites. But for now, worry about obtaining that broad skill set that you said you were originally lacking.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been studying a bit to get ready for a certification. However, I am not quite sure which one I should go for as so many jobs list so many different certs as qualifications.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer, hope it covers this question.

Comment: @SamuelWyattCassady There are many roles within the military and many ways to prepare for each role. You don't try to qual for all of them. Define a clear target, then you can hit it. What's your goal?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Putt's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putt%27s_Law_and_the_Successful_Technocrat):

> "*Technology is dominated by two types of people, those who understand what they do not manage and those who manage what they do not understand.*"

Cyber Security is the same. There is essentially two branches of it.

1. Security Governance (people who manage)
2. Security Operations (people who understand)

My advice is, if you want to be the best of the best. Try and get exposure to the two sides of Cyber Security. If you understand both the Governance and Operations side, you will be more desirable than most other candidates. There are a few different routes you could go with this. I would suggest a graduate programme with a large organisation. These types of programs typically move the person around to different areas, to get a better idea of what areas are involved in Cyber Security.